# Multiple Selection Listbox Used To Create Records In Table

Tags: python, sqlite, listbox, tkinter

I want to be able to take the PatientID that the user selected from the listbox and use it in another table.
This is my code so far:

```
        window=Tk()
        listbox= Listbox(window, width='40', selectmode=EXTENDED)
        window.title('Please choose patients')
        Label(window,text='Please choose the patients to send job to:').grid(row=0, column=0)

        new_db=sqlite3.connect('H:\\patients.db')
        c=new_db.cursor()
        cursor=c.execute("SELECT Patient_id, Patient_forename, Patient_surname FROM PatientsTable")

        for row, row in enumerate(cursor):
            listbox.insert(END, row)

        listbox.grid(row=3, column=0)

        def Availability():
                selection=listbox.get(listbox.curselection())
                PatientsID=selection[0]
                new_db.execute('''INSERT INTO AvailablePatients (Patient_id,Surgery_id,Availablity_response)VALUES(?,?,' ')''',(PatientsID, JobIDValue,))
                new_db.commit()                            
                new_db.close
```

This code works for one selection from the listbox but I need to be able to choose multiple selections and create a record for each. I have tried with for and while loops and looked for questions on stack overflow but couldn't get it to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you not know how to get the values, or do you not know how to take the values and add them to your insert statement?

Comment: I don't know how to get and take multiple values and use them in my insert statement. @BryanOakley